# noty js style is not working in laravel 6

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, laravel-6, noty

I am using noty library for styliss notification: [enter link description here](https://ned.im/noty/#/)

it is working in default theme without styling
I put source css and js in app.blade:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('dashboard_files/plugins/noty/noty.css')}}">
    <script src="{{asset('dashboard_files/plugins/noty/noty.min.js')}}"></script>
```

I put following code in _sessions.blade.php:

```
<script>



@if(session('success'))


  new Noty({
    theme: 'relax',
    type: 'success',
    layout:'topRight',
    text: "{{session('success')}}",
    timeout:2000,
    killer: true
    }).show();

    </script>


    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

add this link .. you must add the reference for theme you wish (mint , etc..) with css file and js file if you not use npm to install the plugin :)